# QSerialPortInfo : Finding the USB hardware location of a virtual serial Port

Tags: qt, serial-port, location, usb

I have a USB hub chip, and a micro controller connected to it on one of its ports.

I am able to enumerate, and communicate with the micro controller with QSerialPortInfo / QSerialPort.
My problem is, that I have to tell if a general USB device is connected to the same USB hub as my micro controller or not.

This should be easy, I can tell the general USB device's hardware location, like "Port_#0001.Hub_#0010", so if the Hub_# number is the same as where the micro controller is connected, I can tell that it is the same hub they are connected to.

The problem is that **QSerialPortInfo.systemLocation()** return with **"\.\COM31"** string, and not someting like "Port_#0002.Hub_#0010".

How can I obtain what USB hardware path does the QSerialPortInfo / QSerialPort belong to?

**Additional info:**

Windows 7, Qt 5.3, C++11

QSerialPortInfo returns information:

```
QSerialPortInfo.portName() == "COM31"
QSerialPortInfo.description() == "LPC USB VCom Port"
QSerialPortInfo.serialNumber() == "" // (Empty string)
```

While windows device manager shows the real USB correctly: (sorry can't post images yet)

DeviceManager > Ports(COM & LPT) > LPC USB VCom Port (COM31)

Properties > General > Location: Port_#0002.Hub_#0010

How could I access this information from my Qt code?

Answer (score 2):

Well, managed to get is working, but its not the desired solution:
I use the **SetupDiGetClassDevs** windows api call to get all devices for a specific GUID, then with the **SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty** winApi I get properties until I find the specific port the MCU is located on, and initialize a QSerialPort with that port name. Then the properties **SPDRP_LOCATION_PATHS** and **SPDRP_LOCATION_INFORMATION** provide information that is usable to detect if a general USB device is on the same hub.

The problem is that this is a "Throw away the high level API that Qt provides and start to mess around with winApi" solution. I would rather avoid this. If there is a more Qt like, and less direct winApi dependent solutions for this it would be appreciated.

Comment: Dang! I was hoping for something that was portable to Linux :-( I have a similar problem where I want to distinguish a"normal" serial device from an USB one. Qt offers no way so far.